# Swift 3 - how to add the button in each annotation with this case

Tags: button, swift3, annotations, mkmapview

I try to find a lot of tutorial for adding the button in annotation.
But it only work on their case or new project. I don't know how to apply it in my case. I am really confuse for how to develop my graduation project.

import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate{

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

//my location

let manager = CLLocationManager()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations[0]

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    print(location.altitude)
    print(location.speed)

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //my location
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()


    let distanceSpan:CLLocationDegrees = 250

    //KT1 Annotation
    let KT1Location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.310491, 114.227998)
    mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(KT1Location, distanceSpan, distanceSpan),animated: true)
    let KT1CSClassPin = KT1Annotation(title: "觀塘工業中心第一期", subtitle: "觀塘道 472-484號", coordinate: KT1Location)
    mapView.addAnnotation( KT1CSClassPin )

    //KT2 Annotation
    let KT2Location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.310724, 114.227626)
    mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(KT2Location, distanceSpan, distanceSpan),animated: true)
    let KT2CSClassPin = KT2Annotation(title: "觀塘工業中心第二期", subtitle: "觀塘道 460-470號", coordinate: KT2Location)
    mapView.addAnnotation( KT2CSClassPin )

    //KT3 Annotation
    let KT3Location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.310957, 114.227255)
    mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(KT3Location, distanceSpan, distanceSpan),animated: true)
    let KT3CSClassPin = KT3Annotation(title: "觀塘工業中心第三期", subtitle: "觀塘道 448-458號", coordinate: KT3Location)
    mapView.addAnnotation( KT3CSClassPin )

    //KT4 Annotation
    let KT4Location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.311364, 114.226883)
    mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(KT4Location, distanceSpan, distanceSpan),animated: true)
    let KT4CSClassPin = KT4Annotation(title: "觀塘工業中心第四期", subtitle: "觀塘道 436-446號", coordinate: KT4Location)
    mapView.addAnnotation( KT4CSClassPin )

    //CP1 Annotation
    let CP1Location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.310459, 114.22516470000005)
    mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CP1Location, distanceSpan, distanceSpan),animated: true)
    let CP1CSClassPin = CP1Annotation(title: "駱駝漆大廈第1座", subtitle: "開源道 62號", coordinate: CP1Location)
    mapView.addAnnotation( CP1CSClassPin )

    //CP3 Annotation
    let CP3Location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.310125, 114.225072)
    mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CP3Location, distanceSpan, distanceSpan),animated: true)
    let CP3CSClassPin = CP3Annotation(title: "駱駝漆大廈第3座", subtitle: "開源道 60號", coordinate: CP3Location)
    mapView.addAnnotation( CP3CSClassPin )

}
```

Comment: I think you should look at Apples "MapCallouts" example, on how to customize pins and their callout bubbles. Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Its that a swift example? Its same like objectiveC program.

Comment: Yes, it's Objective-C. But, if you could be inspired to accomplish your task, you can convert it to Swift, or ask another question.